# How to delete photograph from Google Plus post?

Tags: google-plus, photos

How do I delete a picture from a post on Google+ that I've already posted?

I have already clicked all buttons to try to find a link or a move on the post and didn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

Strangely, you can't delete a picture from a post that you've posted. There's no option to change or remove the picture, and even <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to select all only selects the text.

It appears the only way to delete a picture is to delete the whole post, then repost it without the picture.